# Facebook Audience Network show banner ad

Tags: ios, facebook, banner, facebook-audience-network

When I want to show banner in my iOS app on my test device,following the rules,I add the code like this:

```
[FBAdSettings addTestDevice:@"HASHED ID"];
```

Then the ad works normally.I want to know if I need to remove the code above when I release my app.
Thanks.

Comment: addTestDevice() is to guarantee you will receive an ad during testing. It should not be used in production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to remove the code so that your app user will see real ads rather than test ads.

Comment: @EricZhao Facebook Audience Network is still an extremely new ad network. The inventory of ads they have available to fill requests will be low at first, but improve over time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can leave this code. It's only useful when you test on your device and just tell the framework that your device is a test device.

But in production, it should not impact other users at all.